# game that generates random answers to user input is generating the same answer regardless of what the user input is

Tags: javascript, html, callback

/*
I have a game that generates random answers to questions input by users, but the answers are not being generated randomly. The code for that (generating the answers) is setup correctly as far as I know. The problem seems (to me) to be that after the last event listener and callback function (clearBtn) resets the user input, the (addh4) function needs to be called again to create a new (and different) h4 element (or answer) to a new user question. Right now the same answer is being generated regardless of what the user input is. I’m not sure if I’m approaching this correctly. Thanks…
*/

```
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Magic Eight Ball</h1>
        
        <h4>Ask Your Question…</h4>
1   
    <input type="text"id="textInput"><br>
            <div id="btnContainer">
                <button id="btn">Go for it</button>
                <button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
            </div>  
    </div>



<script>
    //generate random num
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    
    //anwser index corresponds to num var
    const answers =['Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now', 'Don’t count on it', 'It is certain', 'Most likely', 'No', 'Outlook not so good', 'Outlook good', 'Signs point to yes', 'Very doubtful', 'Without a doubt', 'Yes'];
    
    const textInput = document.querySelector("#textInput");
    const clearBtn = document.querySelector("#clearBtn");
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    const h1 =document.querySelector("h1");
    const h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    
    const generateAnswer = () => {
    answers.forEach((answer, index) => {
        if(num === index){
            h4.textContent = `"${answer}"`;
            h1.append(h4);
        }
        });
    }; 
   
    btn.addEventListener("click", generateAnswer);

    clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        h4.remove();
        textInput.value = "";
    });
    
</script>
```

Comment: Your code only generates one random number. You need to do that *inside* `generateAnswer()` each time it is called.

Comment: In addition to what Pointy said, you can get a random element from an array with `answer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)]`. You don't need the answers.forEach. In addition, this will get additional answers as you add them and won't try to get answers that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the value of `num` never changes, for changing it you have to declare it inside the function in order to create a diferent number each time you call the function.

```js
const answers =['Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now', 'Don’t count on it', 'It is certain', 'Most likely', 'No', 'Outlook not so good', 'Outlook good', 'Signs point to yes', 'Very doubtful', 'Without a doubt', 'Yes'];
    
    
    const textInput = document.querySelector("#textInput");
    const clearBtn = document.querySelector("#clearBtn");
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    const h1 =document.querySelector("h1");
    const h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    
    const generateAnswer = () => {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
     h4.textContent = answers[num];
     h1.append(h4);
    }; 
   
    btn.addEventListener("click", generateAnswer);

    clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        h4.remove();
        textInput.value = "";
    });
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <h1>Magic Eight Ball</h1>
        
        <h4>Ask Your Question…</h4>
1   
    <input type="text"id="textInput"><br>
            <div id="btnContainer">
                <button id="btn">Go for it</button>
                <button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
            </div>  
    </div>
```